# Windows: how to check for every folder with modify (M) right for authenticated users?

Tags: windows, wmic

I want to see which directories on my Windows 7 machine can be modified by Authenticated user (you see it when you run `icacls c:\path\to\directory`),
I wanted to make a batch script but I'm sure there is an easier way (with **wmic** maybe ?)

Here is what I tried:

```
for /R %f in (.) do cacls %f | findstr /i "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(ID)(M)"
```

But for some occurences of this loop I get:

```
Displays or modifies access control lists (ACLs) of files
```

And other stuffs but "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(ID)(M)" is not displayed for those directories.

Thanks

Comment: We are not a script writting service.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted to make a bash script using a recursive function which would have walk through every directories of the system, but I don't find how to make a recursive function in batch

Comment: So write a bash script, that runs through every directory, one level deep.  Once you get to that point we can help you make it a recursive algorithm.  What won't happen, is somebody writting the entire script for you, because we are not a script writting service.

Comment: Read next output first: `for /R %f in (.) do @echo "%~dpnxf" & icacls "%~dpnxf" /C | findstr /I /C:"NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:"`

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks a lot it seems to work but I can't figure out how to not display directories that does not match (when it match you have "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:" that displays just next to the dir name, and when it does not just the dir name is displayed)

Comment: `for /R %f in (.) do @icacls "%~ff" /C | findstr /I /C:"NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:"&&@echo "%~ff"` unfortunately writes output in reverse order (ACLs first, then folder path); for more nice output, write a complex batch script rather than such oneliner.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will, but is it not possible to start the loop from a specific directory (by specify it between the brackets) ?

Comment: I'd prefer `for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /B /S /AD "starting directory\*"') do …`. Ehm, it's because I don't like `for /R` loops:)))